# How to read a line which doesn't end with new line or carriage return character in java?

Tags: java

I am using BufferedReader as follows,

```
BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   System.out.println(stdin.readLine());
}
```

And the input given is as follows,

```
1
2
3
```

The last input doesn't end with `\n` or `\r`,  therefore for 3 readLine() will expect input from user unless user presses enter key

Any solution for this using Scanner ?

Actually, I got into this problem while solving , [Quora Question Nearby](http://www.quora.com/challenges#nearby), In their [conditions](https://www.interviewstreet.com/recruit/challenges/faq/view#trailing) they have mentioned following lines,

Does the last line in the input test case end with a newline? [link]

Nope. No trailing spaces or newlines.

---

[Link for Code](https://github.com/pradeephrish/quorachallenges/blob/master/Solution.java), Submitted at above page, test cases are failing

For Test Case Zero, It shows following output ,
[image]
Since, expected output is blank, it means my codes still expects `\n or \r` which is not provided by input

Comment: Are the inputs all expected to be integers?

Comment: A line without a line terminator is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the input is terminated - which would be the case if standard input is actually being redirected from a file, for example - then it's fine. `BufferedReader.readLine` will still return the last line from its input, when it detects the end of the underlying data.

Given that this is an automated challenge, I would *expect* this to be the case - I'd expect it to be run as something like

```
java Solution < input.txt
```

So basically, I believe you should be fine.

Comment: Ah so `readLine()` returns on \n, \r, or EOF? Then the Javadocs are terribly unclear on that last part. In addition they mention "or null if the end of the stream has been reached"...which I suppose is somewhat untrue.

Comment: exactly..unless he's actually getting the input from the user not file..:)

Comment: not working, just updated question for the code link, if possible please check

Comment: @WilliamGaul: It returns `null` if the end of the steam has been reached *and there's no more data to return*. (Basically it returns the last line, and then null on the next call.)

Comment: @pradeep: "Not working" isn't nearly enough description. Are you able to get any sort of diagnostic output on this? For example, can you create a short program which *just* reads the input lines and copies them to the output? I'm not going to work through all your code just to find there's a bug completely unrelated to the actual question.

Comment: @Jon: sorry about that, actually code is working if user presses enter key at the end of input, i will check with their team and update here

Comment: @pradeep: This is an automated system - there *is* no user pressing a key. That's my point.

Comment: yes, it works exactly as you mentioned, it's coming from file, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the output without pressing enter,it is impossible.
Because System.in stream doesn't allow you to take input without pressing enter by default.You have to use a third party library like [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) for that.

Comment: I can't use thirdy party, check the links provided, In Java they expect only Solution class , no third party, since it runs on test server